# conv1D does 2d convolution by default

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

So most guides to CNNs explain convolution in one dimension as a series of 1D kernels being convolved with your input sequence (Like traditional FIR filters). However, as far as i can understand, the default of conv1d implements convolution across all your channels for each output (essentially 2D convolution). 
If the traditional FIR filter implementation is desired, you should specify groups=in_channels.

Inspecting the weights seems to verify this:

```
from torch import nn

C1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=3, out_channels=6, kernel_size=7)
C2 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=3, out_channels=6, kernel_size=7,groups=3)
C3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=6, kernel_size=7)
C4 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=6, kernel_size=7, groups=3)

print(C1.weight.shape, '<-- 6 filters which convolve across two dimensions')
print(C2.weight.shape, '<-- 6 filters which convolve across one dimensions')
print(C3.weight.shape, '<-- 6 filters which convolve across three dimensions')
print(C4.weight.shape, '<-- 6 filters which convolve across two dimensions')
```

providing the following output:

```
torch.Size([6, 3, 7]) <-- 6 filters which convolve across two dimensions
torch.Size([6, 1, 7]) <-- 6 filters which convolve across one dimensions
torch.Size([6, 3, 7, 7]) <-- 6 filters which convolve across three dimensions
torch.Size([6, 1, 7, 7]) <-- 6 filters which convolve across two dimensions
```

Am i wrong in this observation?

If a am correct, i believe the naming of conv1d is quite confusing as it implies 1d convolution.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider:

1) Conv1d runs a convolution with a kernel of 1 dimension (vector). C1  and C2 would have a kernel of size (7).

2) Conv2d runs a convolution with a kernel of 2 dimensions (matrix). C3 and C4 would have a kernel of size (7, 7).

3) Groups are a way to control connections between the input and output channels, were you can produce several simultaneous convolutions at the same time.

More information [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html).